# VueJs: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function, "withScopeId"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

We've been pushing updates successfully to our Vue applications in recent weeks and after some very minimal changes yesterday (property name changes and removing some purely semantic characters) we are experiencing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.fae3 (XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:53612)
    at n (XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:30)
    at 0012 (XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:94)
    at XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:11
    at XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:3
    at Object.e977 (XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary.umd.js:1)
    at o (app.2df3392d.js:formatted:39)
    at CustomerServiceManagement.umd.js:3
    at Object.7091 (CustomerServiceManagement.umd.js:1)
    at o (app.2df3392d.js:formatted:39)
```

We debugged the code and found the error occurring on this line:

```
const _withId = /*#__PURE__*/Object(external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_["withScopeId"])("data-v-569a422e")
```

We build Vue components into libraries, push them to a Verdaccio repo, and then add them as dependencies into a larger project. The library in questions (`XCustomerServiceOptionsLibrary`) and the larger Vue application build fine, but produce the above error when serving.

I am starting to think there were a version change to one of our Vue dependencies that is causing issues. Here are our package.json files:

*Library*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "graphql": "^14.2.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.28",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.16",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

App

```
"apollo-boost": "^0.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "graphql": "^14.2.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.28",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.16",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.36.1",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
```

Comment: any resolution?

Comment: How are you bundling your library? Could you share you webpack.config.js

Comment: Hi anyone find solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Vue version to Vue3.

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve your answer (add link to docs, proof that it fixes the problem...).